# showDocsPicker - Add to a popup?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a gadget that is very small and placed in a sidebar such that its size is about 100px wide.  I have a button that when clicked opens the showDocsPicker.  I am looking for a solution where I can add the UI of the showDocsPicker to a popup or something such that the full view of the dialog can be seen...  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I've seen this in the documentation which is not encouraging:

"Unlike most UiApp objects, DocsListDialog should not be added to the UiInstance."

Anyone else try this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code which will open docsPicker in fullView.

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var btn = app.createButton('Show Docs Picker');
  app.add(btn);
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('showdocsPicker_');
  btn.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}

function showdocsPicker_(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('listSelectedDocs_');
  app.createDocsListDialog().showDocsPicker().addSelectionHandler(handler).setMultiSelectEnabled(true)
    //for multiple selection
    .setMultiSelectEnabled(true);
  return app;
}

function listSelectedDocs_(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  for(var i in e.parameter.items){
    for(var j in e.parameter.items[i]){
      app.add(app.createLabel(e.parameter.items[i][j]));
    }
    app.add(app.createLabel('-------------'))
  }
  return app;
}
```

Comment: I have not tried using jQuery UI.. is this what you are recommending?